# why does function enumFromThenTo behaves not same as it is defined in GHC.Enum?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Learnt from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Enum.html#enumFromThenTo), the definition of function `enumFromThenTo` is

```
enumFromThenTo      :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
enumFromThenTo x1 x2 y = map toEnum [fromEnum x1, fromEnum x2 .. fromEnum y]
```

However, when I tested the function with code below:

```
import GHC.Enum
myEnumFromThenTo :: Enum a => a->a->a->[a]
myEnumFromThenTo x1 x2 y = map toEnum [fromEnum x1, fromEnum x2 .. fromEnum y]

xs1 :: [Float]
xs1 = myEnumFromThenTo 1 3 10

xs2 :: [Float]
xs2 = enumFromThenTo 1 3 10

 -- -- | Used in Haskell's translation of @[n,n'..m]@.
-- enumFromThenTo      :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
```

The value of `xs1` is `[1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,9.0]` while the value of `xs2` is `[1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,9.0,11.0]`

Why would it be so?

Comment: Basically, the example is dividing the interval from 1 to 10 into units with a width of 3-1=2. Hence we get 4.5 units, which we have to round. If we round those as 4 units, we get 5 points as extremes. Otherwise, we round them as 5 units, and we get 6 points. Rounding exact half-integers is very unstable, since any error may affect the outcome. For this reason, two different numerical algorithms which round half integers and would aim to compute the same result can easily yield different outputs.

Answer (score 5):

The definition you use is just the default definition from the class Individual instances are free to use different definitions. Indeed, the actual instance `Enum Double` is defined in `GHC.Float` and makes use of a different definition.

Copying the relevant comment from the source file:

> The @Enum@ instances for Floats and Doubles are slightly unusual. The @toEnum@ function truncates numbers to Int. The definitions of @enumFrom@ and @enumFromThen@ allow floats to be used in arithmetic series: [0,0.1 .. 1.0]. However, roundoff errors make these somewhat dubious. This example may have either 10 or 11 elements, depending on how 0.1 is represented. NOTE: The instances for Float and Double do not make use of the default methods for @enumFromTo@ and @enumFromThenTo@, as these rely on there being a `non-lossy' conversion to and from Ints. Instead we make use of the 1.2 default methods (back in the days when Enum had Ord as a superclass) for these (@numericEnumFromTo@ and @numericEnumFromThenTo@ below.)